# How to embed a view (with contextual filters) into a node or another view?

Tags: 7, entities, views

I'm using the modules below with the [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) module to create a views block of all **referenced nodes** in the entity reference fields.

- [Entity API](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity)
- [Entity Reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference)

There is no problem to create a views that lists all the referenced nodes based on [this](http://overboordwebprojects.blogspot.com.tr/2013/11/drupal-7-how-to-create-views-block-of.html) tutorial.

### What I want to do is to **embed** this views into nodes.

I tried both the [EVA](https://www.drupal.org/project/eva) and [Views Field View](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_field_view) modules but couldn't be success (no result). The view I want to embed into nodes uses **contextual filters** and **relationships** and I think while using this view into a node or another view, the contextual filter doesn't work.

[image]

### So, how I can embed this view (with contextual filter) into a node or another view?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Using panels module you can create a "pane view" for your view and easily pass any argument as view contextual filter .

here is a tutorial about [views content panes](https://drupalize.me/videos/basics-views-content-panes?p=1147)

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to use panels module for only that. I'm trying to find a right way to pass arguments.

Answer (score 1):

You can embed a view into a node using [Insert View](https://www.drupal.org/project/insert_view).
You can have your contextual filters setup as arguments in the format below,

```
[view:<view_name>=<display_name>=<argument>]
```

You can embed a view into a view as a field using [Views Field View](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_field_view).
You will have to place your contextual filters from the replacement patterns as shown in the below picture.

[image: Views Field View Image Screenshot]

Comment: As I said in my question, I tried to use the Views Field View module but while passing the arguments (contextual filters) there is a problem I think, I couldn't do this.